# Java DigitExtractor

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with an assignment that I'm working on. Here is the prompt:

Create a DigitExtractor application that prompts the user for an integer (in the range: 0-999) and then displays either the ones, tens, or hundreds digit of the number. The user will select from a menu which digit they wish to display.

This program needs to be written as a class.  The menu will be your driver program that you submit with the class so your instructor can use it to test the class.

Here is my code for it:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class TestingMenu
{
    public int number;
    public int units;
    public int tens;
    public int hundreds;

    public TestingMenu(int input)
    {
        number = input;
        units = number%10;

        tens = number%10;

        hundreds = number%10;
    }

    public int return_units()
    {
        return units;
    } 

    public int return_tens()
    {
        return tens;
    }

    public int return_hundreds()
    {
        return hundreds;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        TestingMenu num;
        int choice;

        int input;
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Enter a number(0-999): ");
            input = kbReader.nextInt();
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Options");
            System.out.println("1) Units");
            System.out.println("2) Tens");
            System.out.println("3) Hundreds");
            System.out.println("4) Quit");
            num = new TestingMenu(input);
            System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
            choice = kbReader.nextInt();

            switch(choice)
            {
                case 1: 
                System.out.println("The units digit is: " + num.return_units());
                break;

                case 2: 
                System.out.println("The tens digit is: " + num.return_tens());
                break;

                case 3: System.out.println("The hundreds digit is: " + num.return_hundreds());
                break;

                case 4: 
                System.exit(4);
                break;

                 default: 
                 System.out.print("Invalid. Select a number from the given options.");
                 choice = kbReader.nextInt();
             }
        }
        while(choice != 4);
    }
}
```

I think I've almost got it, but I'm having issues whenever I test it. When I input a number such as 987 and I run all the options from 1-3, I keep getting 7 for the ones, tens, and hundreds. 4 exits the program and works okay, but I've tested this numerous times. Overall, it seems to only print the last digit.

Enter a number(0-999): 987

Options 
1) Units
2) Tens
3) Hundreds
4) Quit
Enter your choice: 1
The units digit is: 7
Enter a number(0-999): 987

Options
1) Units
2) Tens
3) Hundreds
4) Quit
Enter your choice: 2
The tens digit is: 7
Enter a number(0-999): 987

Options
1) Units
2) Tens
3) Hundreds
4) Quit
Enter your choice: 3
The hundreds digit is: 7
Enter a number(0-999): 987

Options
1) Units
2) Tens
3) Hundreds
4) Quit
Enter your choice: 4

Could someone help me identify the error? I don't really know what went wrong with this program despite working on it for a few hours. Thanks in advance. All the help and feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: i don't see all your code but you are `%10` to all your values `tens` `hundreds` `units`

Comment: note that % works like any other operator in that `number` will still be the same after doing %10

Answer (score 0):

You had a few issues, I would suggest you review this very carefully -

```
// Why make them public?
private int units = 0;
private int tens = 0;
private int hundreds = 0;

public TestingMenu(int input) {
  // Convert it to a String.
  String str = String.valueOf(input);
  if (str.length() == 1) {
    // ones and only ones.
    units = Integer.parseInt(str);
  } else if (str.length() == 2) {
    // tens and ones.
    tens = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0, 1));
    units = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(1, 2));
  } else if (str.length() == 3) {
    // hundreds, tens and ones.
    hundreds = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(0, 1));
    tens = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(1, 2));
    units = Integer.parseInt(str.substring(2, 3));
  }
}

// Just use get, PLEASE!
public int getUnits() {
  return units;
}

public int getTens() {
  return tens;
}

public int getHundreds() {
  return hundreds;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
  try {
    TestingMenu num;
    int choice;

    do {
      System.out.print("Enter a number(0-999): ");
      num = new TestingMenu(kbReader.nextInt());

      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("Options");
      System.out.println("1) Units");
      System.out.println("2) Tens");
      System.out.println("3) Hundreds");
      System.out.println("4) Quit");
      System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
      choice = kbReader.nextInt();

      if (choice == 1) {
        System.out.println("The units digit is: "
            + num.getUnits());
      } else if (choice == 2) {
        System.out.println("The tens digit is: "
            + num.getTens());
      } else if (choice == 3) {
        System.out.println("The hundreds digit is: "
            + num.getHundreds());
      } else if (choice != 4) {
        // We want 4 to fall through and terminate the loop.
        System.out.print("Invalid. Select a number "
            + "from the given options.");
        choice = kbReader.nextInt();
      }
    } while (choice != 4);
  } finally {
    // close the Scanner.
    kbReader.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is I would is I would use your Scanner to take input as a string so you can use .length() to get the length and .charAt() to display them...remember that charAt is like arrays in that the indexes start from 0, length does not. If you need them to be ints you can use Integer.parseInt() (be sure to check it is a number before trying this cause it will throw an exception but with a boolean and a try catch you can continue to ask users for input until they get it right like this

```
boolean notComplete = true;
while(notComplete = true){  
try{ userinput = //get input somehow
Integer.parseInt(userinput);
//do whatever
boolean complete = true;
}catch(NumberFormatException e){
//get input and repeat it will keep trying until the boolean is updated
}})
```

But for this I don't think it matters how you keep it as long as you display it. You could also add an array of Strings that have indexs that correspond to what they are...meaning something like this:

```
String[] s = {"ones", "tens", "hundreds"};
```

so that when the user says 1, 2 or 3 to pick what should be displayed you can subtract one call .charAt on the string to display the number and print the index of the array s at the same index to tell the user what it is.